# Substitution in differential equation - Step by step

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, education

I have the differential equation:

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = D \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial z^2}$$

to solve it, the author of my book (page 421 Cooney - Biomedical engineering principles) carries out the following replacement:

$$-2\zeta \frac{dX}{d \zeta} = \frac{d^2 X}{d \zeta^2}$$

with $X=1-\frac{C}{C_S}$ and $\zeta =\frac{z}{(4Dt)^{1/2}}$.

How can I come back to the original equation? I tried:

$$\frac{dX}{d\zeta}=\frac{dX}{dC}\frac{dC}{dt}\frac{dt}{d\zeta}$$

$$\frac{dX}{dC}=-\frac{1}{C_S}$$

$$\frac{dt}{d\zeta} = \frac{d}{d\zeta}\left(z^2(\zeta) \frac{1}{4D\zeta^2}\right) = 2z(\zeta)\frac{dz(\zeta)}{d\zeta}\frac{1}{4D\zeta^2}+\frac{-2z^2(\zeta)}{4D\zeta^3}$$

Now I evaluate $dz/d\zeta$:

$$z=\zeta (4Dt)^{1/2}$$

$$\frac{dz}{d\zeta}=(4Dt)^{1/2}$$

Thus:

$$\frac{dt}{d\zeta} = \frac{d}{d\zeta}\left(z^2(\zeta) \frac{1}{4D\zeta^2}\right) = 2z(\zeta)\frac{dz(\zeta)}{d\zeta}\frac{1}{4D\zeta^2}+\frac{-2z^2(\zeta)}{4D\zeta^3}=
\frac{2 \zeta (4Dt)^{1/2} (4Dt)^{1/2}}{4D\zeta^2}-\frac{2\zeta^2 4Dt}{4D\zeta^3}=
\frac{2t}{\zeta}-\frac{2t}{\zeta}=0$$

What did I do wrong?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Can you show us the book, in particular the specific page?

Comment: Where did you get $\frac{dX}{d\zeta}=\frac{dX}{dC}\frac{dC}{dt}\frac{dt}{d\zeta}$? $C$ is not a function of only $t$, it depends on $z$ too.

Comment: And $t$ is a function of both $\zeta$ and $z$, so you cannot write $\frac {dt}{d\zeta}$ either. It looks like yuor problem is failing to recognize the difference between derivatives and partial derivatives.

Comment: Hello @PaulSinclair can you show me the first steps please? In this way maybe I'll figure out the problem.